# How to Decode and Play a Video file using Java to a single monitor connected Via USB or HDMI

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I am doing a project using a Raspberry PI and I am using Arch Linux Arm as my OS. What I want to do is that to decode and play a video file to a Monitor connected to HDMI port of the Pi or a USB port. How to do this using java, can someone point me in the right direction, I know that I can use Xuggle, I will appreciate if someone can give me instructions on what to do or follow ?
thank You.

Comment: it is good if i can do this using a USB connected Monitor, I don't any OS things to show up in the Monitor if my java program crashes :D. because I want this Program to run 24/7

Comment: why would a USB monitor be any better in case of a crash of your program?

Comment: if the OS doesn't give any Display input to the HDMI monitor, which is default in Arch Linux ARM. and if I plug in a USB monitor (I think Arch Linux will not Give Display to the USB monitor aswell) and then only my program will talk to the monitor connected via USB so if it crashed, monitor will not receive anything at all

Comment: you need to go through the OS to "talk to the monitor"...

Comment: I am not sure if there is some limitations on decoding any video format for RPi  using i.e. Java. `omxplayer` is the standard built in player in RPi, but this is not a library but a program. Regarding the USB, what is the plan?...